# Phantom page can't get rid of/can't get at to change

Tags: pages

Hi: I need to add a page to my very first WP site, which, at present, only has 4 pages on it (though one page has photo albums on it, which generate their own pages). I built the theme, the site is very simple, and up until now, has been fine.

But now I seem to have a phantom page I can't find, can't delete, and can't change.
The site is at http://www.twistintomradio.com

If you type in another nonexistent page url in a browser, such as: http://www.twistintomradio.com/about.html, you get a 404 page, as is proper.

But if you type in: http://www.twistintomradio.com/mountainrose.html, you get a page with the mountain rose logo that I placed on the homepage. I don't remember creating this page, but if I did, I deleted it as it does not come up when I go to "ALL Pages" in the Admin. But I want to build that page now. But when I "ADD NEW" page and name it mountainrose.html, the page with the logo appears in my browser, no matter what I do. I've cleared the caches in different browsers, on different computers, etc. I've cleared the WP cache (using Quick Cache plugin.) That page still comes up. I've trashed and permanently deleted this attempt to build the page now, it isn't in my list of pages, it isn't in the trash, but still the page comes up in browsers.

I've looked on the server in the wp-content directory - no such page there. Where is this page coming from? How can I get rid of it?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's an [attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments) post. when you upload files, WP generates an attachment, which is just a type of post in WP, and has it's own URL. your image is named mountainrose, hence the mountainrose.html URL.

Also, you should accept answers to your questions, people will be unwilling to help you with a 0% accept rate. I'm feeling kind today.

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I Accept? I certainly haven't meant to not do so -

Comment: @PVA - There should be a check mark that you can click below the vote up/down buttons next to each answer. To be honest, I've never asked a question, so I'm not quite sure what the UI looks like!

Comment: OK, clicked the checkmark. What if you get a couple of good answers; do you have to select one with the checkmark and give "up arrows" to the rest? Also, you guys should add this to the FAQ's - I'm afraid I'd never noticed the symbols before and didn't realize their significance. I always said Thanks, though. Should I go in and Accept on my old questions?

Comment: Also, didn't realize how naming a graphic the same as a page could create this scenario. Learn something new every day...